# Render returned no data - trying to call component multiple times in forEach

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and am really struggling.

I want to create a small app that:

1. Reads in data from my `data.js` file (an object)
2. Outputs it each sub-object info into a `card` component

I have created a component called `Lister` where the data is imported, and iterated over using `forEach`.

I then want to call the `Card` component and output the data on the page in this component for each sub-object.

However I keep getting the error that the `render` in my `Lister` component does not return anything.

It is a small component so here it is in full:

```
import React from 'react';
import data from "../../data/data";
import Card from "../card";

class Lister extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            Object.keys(data()).forEach(function(key) {
                <Card data={data()[key]}/>
            })
        )
    }

}

export default Lister;
```

Answer (score 0):

For React you'll want to be using `.map` to handle your loops. Also any time you're using JSX, remember you add the open and closing curly braces `{}` (you were missing one right before Object). Lastly, everything inside of the return inside of `render` needs to be wrapped in a single root node like a  `<div>` for example.

Here's an example of how you might rewrite this:

```
import React from 'react';
import data from "../../data/data";
import Card from "../card";

class Lister extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const items = data();
        return (
            <div>
                {Object.keys(items).map(function(key, index) {
                    return <Card key={index} data={items[key]}/>
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Lister;
```

Comment: This answer was close though missing the crucial `return` in front of `<Card .. />` as suggested below. However after adding this I am getting error `Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.`

Comment: Ah yes, always forget that part, I'll add it in. And I'll add in the key part too.

Comment: I understand now that the `key` suggestion is required by React, but wondered if you could explain a bit why :)

Comment: Sure, as I understand it, the `key` prop is actually how React internally keeps track of which items have changed when the parent component re-renders. When each item has a unique key (like an ID in a database), it makes it easy to pinpoint the item that needs to update. Also, even though we're doing it in this example, generally React advises against using the loop's index for keys. It's better to use an ID param directly from the data if available. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: Also, would you mind marking this answer as correct if it accurately solves your problem? It helps me, and I hope it helps you too!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `.map` instead of `.forEach`. With `.forEach`, you can handle that like this:

```
render() {
  const items = data();
  let cards=[];

  Object.keys(items).forEach(function(key,i) {              
      objArray.push(<Card key={i} data={items[key]})
  });

  return (<div>{cards}</div>)
}
```